# In iOS lastModifiedDate using phone gap is not working

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm doing an iOS app using phonegap, in that in need lastModified date for my processing. When in use the function,it returns me the device date(current/today's date)

code i used for your reference

```
<script>
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files; 
        var output = [];
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
         output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ')- ',           
                        f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                        f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                        '</li>');
        }
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
    }

        document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**file.lastModifiedDate;**

- it Returns the last modified date of the file.
- Files without a known last modified date use the current date instead.
- And it is not supported in Safari (WebKit)(iphone default web browser)